# how to use bundle install without network access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I have a Windows 2012 server that is on an internal network. I used Railsinstaller to put the basic framework on the system. Rails new doesn't work when I reach the bundler section since I can't reach the net.

I have used "gem install rails -i repo --no-rdoc --no-ri" on a net accessible system then placed the gems on my server and ran "gem install --force --local *.gem".

Then "rails new D:\DTS_WEB --edge" and now fail at "unable to connect to github.com". Trying to start the rails server fails telling me that nothing has been checked out.

I modified my gems file with 
"gem 'rails', path: '....\Ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\'" but it still tries github.

I installed git with Railsinstaller along with rails. How can I get past this last obstacle and force everything to use local resources?

Is it possible to build everything on the net accessible node and just copy it into place on the server to use? My first attempt at that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a machine that has a network connection, you can install your app's gems to a directory within the project using `--path`:

```
$ bundle install --path=vendor/bundle
```

Then, you can copy the project folder (along with all the gems in vendor/bundle) to your internal machine.

Comment: I ran the bundle install --path=vendor/bundle. It also created a .bundle folder with commands that indicate bundle should use vendor/bundle.

Comment: It still doesn't work with my rails server command. My gem path variable looks correct, at least to me, but do I need to override a path somewhere to  pick up the new bundle file on the server?

Comment: Happy days are here again. I got messed up between having rails 4.2 on the server and 5.0 on the net access system but once I got that sorted out I finally have the welcome page up and running.
Thank you Meagar for helping me with this. 

Using the bundle install with the path option got what I needed to get this working.